# Pass variable value as argument from one script to another shell script, as an argument

Tags: shell, arguments

I have two shell scripts, one is my own script and another is a 3rd party stuff.
I take a path-to-file as argument in script1. 
Script2 is a 3rd party script which takes path-to-file as an argument. I do not wish to modify this script.

I am doing something like this, in script1,

```
a=$1
./script2 $a
```

But the $a is being passed as a string.. as in, '$a' is being passed and not the actual value of variable a :(

Is there a way in which I can achieve this? Please help!

Comment: What's wrong with this? A path is actually a string.

Comment: In sh, all variables are strings.  There is nothing else.

Comment: I meant to say, the path (content of variable a) is not being passed to script2.. instead, '$a' is being passed.. lemme edit the question..

Comment: @DavideBerra .. hope my questions makes sense now.. please suggest

Comment: Is that exactly what you are doing, or just "something like"? You didn't by any chance write the actual line as `./script '$a'` did you? (If that was the case, just change the 's to "s.)

Answer (score 0):

```
my_script.sh
=======================================
#!/bin/bash
1st="sam"
2nd="victor"
3rd="cris"
/home/admin/Third_party.sh "$1st" "$2nd" "$3rd"


Third_party.sh
=======================================
#!/bin/bash
echo "1st value is: $1 ....."
echo "2nd value is: $2 ....."
echo "3rd value is: $3 ....."
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use single quote to pass variable . like '$1st' in your case.